# How do I add a node from a view to user profile field?

Tags: 7, views, nodes, users

I have list of courses of course content type in a view. I want to add "add course" button with every listing of node in view. 
When a user is logged in he can add a course to its profile information. so that profile information shows all the added courses from view in the profile. For example: List of courses taken by user.
I have used entityreference module to attach nodes to user profile. But I have no idea how to do it from a view listing.

How do I add a node from a view to user profile field?

Comment: I don't understand your question, so I am just guessing here. In views, under advanced, maybe you need to add a relationship of referenced or referencing.

Comment: It is kind of add to cart button for products. I have to show in profile information of user that this user has taken these courses.

Comment: What do you mean by `View Listing`?

Comment: Means how to add a button with every listing of node in a view. Exactly like add to cart which adds product in a cart. I want user to select courses in a view and add to their profile information.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a `Global: text area` in views header and input below HTML in the content.

```html
<a href="/node/add/course">Add Course</a>
```

Comment: I think I was not able to explain myself clearly. I don't want to add course node. I want to add already listed courses to profile information of user. If a user add courses from view it should show under the profile information of user. For example list of courses taken.

Comment: I feel confused. Can you update your question to clarify? Thanks.